# String comma delimited to JsonArray

Tags: json, delphi

I am using delphi xe7, win8.1

My question is simple, but I am a newbie in Json.

I have a comma delimited string to convert to JSONArray.

```
var s:string;
    ja:JSONArray;
begin
s:='a,b,c,d,e,f';//--> can have many items comma delimited.
ja:=JSONArray.Create;
//???Convert string comma delimited to JSONArray
ja:=ConvertStringDelimitedToJsonArray(s);
end;
```

I´d like to know how to code the function ConvertStringDelimitedToJsonArray with a string as input parameter and output a JSONArray.

Is there a delphi function to do it directly?

Comment: Why use JSON? Don't you just split the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JSON array is just a list of element divided by comma and enclosed by square brackets, so I think that given your input data, you could simply do something like this:

```
s := 'a,b,c,d,e,f';
s := Format("[%s]", [s]);
ja := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(TEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s),0) as TJSONArray;
```

Comment: Sorry, but it does not work.  i did: s := Format('["%s"]', [s]);
ja := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(TEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s),0) as TJSONArray;  The result is ["a,b,c,d,e,f"]. I need the resut ["a","b","c","d","e","f"]

Comment: Adapt the solution to your needs, maybe you will have to quote each element of your input CSV ...

Comment: It makes no sense to me that you want a `TJSONArray` object. What are you going to do with that? Pull out each value? Well, you had to do that already when you parsed your comma separated input. In which case there is no place at all for JSON.